# General many-to-many relationship problem ( Postgresql )

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-relationship

i have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."auctions" (
"id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
"auction_value_key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
"ctime" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
"mtime" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "pk_XXXX2" PRIMARY KEY("id"), 
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."auction_values" (
 "id" NUMERIC DEFAULT nextval('default_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL, 
 "fk_auction_value_key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 "key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 "value" TEXT, 
 "ctime" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
 "mtime" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "pk_XXXX1" PRIMARY KEY("id"), 
);
```

if i want to create a many-to-many relationship on the auction_value_key like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."auction_values"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "auction_values_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("fk_auction_value_key")
    REFERENCES "public"."auctions"("auction_value_key")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

i get this SQL error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "auctions"
```

Question:

As you might see, i want "auction_values" to be be "reused" by different auctions without duplicating them for every auction... So i don't want a key relation on the "id" field in the auctions table...

Am i thinking wrong here or what is the deal? ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra table to model a many-to-many relationship. It will contain the mappings between auctions and auction_values. It needs two columns: auction_id and auction_value_id.

Comment: This is the classical approach to normalisation, Bravo

Comment: Probably right, but not necessarily :) Maybe `auction_value_key` groups the set of rows from `auction_values`? In that case proposed schema is not right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `auction_values` to be reused by different auctions, you should declare a constraint the other way round:

```
ALTER TABLE auctions
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_auction_values
FOREIGN KEY (auction_value_key)
REFERENCES auction_values (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

> In the context of relational
>   databases, a foreign key  is a
>   referential constraint between two
>   tables.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)  The foreign key identifies
>   a column or a set of columns in one
>   (referencing) table that refers to set
>   of columns in another (referenced)
>   table. The columns in the referencing
>   table must be the primary key or other
>   candidate key in the referenced table.
>   The values in one row of the
>   referencing columns must occur in a
>   single row in the referenced table.
>   Thus, a row in the referencing table
>   cannot contain values that don't exist
>   in the referenced table (except
>   potentially NULL). This way references
>   can be made to link information 
>   together and it is an essential part
>   of database normalization. Multiple
>   rows in the referencing table may
>   refer to the same row in the
>   referenced table. Most of the time, it
>   reflects the one (master table, or
>   referenced table) to many (child
>   table, or referencing table)
>   relationship.

As Quassnoi points out, it sounds as if you want to have multiple rows in `auctions` reference single rows in `auction_values`.

For that the master or referenced table is `auction_values` and child or referencing table is auction_values.

If on the other hand Alex is right and you want to reference multiple rows in the `auction_values` you will need another table.

This table will help you convert the many-to-many relationship (which can not be directly realized on the physical database level) to two one-to-many relationships.

Generally you could have this table store ids from the two starting tables and in this way you can associate any combination of the records from `auction_values` and `auctions`.

However, this might be too general and you might actually be after a table `auction_value_keys (auction_value_key)`